# Solution of the inequality $2ec{\sqrt{ad}}\lt dc^2+ae^2$

Tags: inequality, radicals

I just want to find a way to prove that the inequality 
$2ec{\sqrt{ad}}\lt dc^2+ae^2$
is true because I need it for a prove. Thanks for your help!

Comment: AM-GM inequality gives it in one step

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I can go on with my main proof :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting
with a magic inequality,
here is a derivation:

$\begin{array}\\
2ec{\sqrt{ad}}\lt dc^2+ae^2\\
\iff\\
4e^2c^2ad\lt d^2c^4+2dc^2ae^2+a^2e^4
\quad\text{(squaring both sides)}\\
\iff\\
0\lt d^2c^4-2dc^2ae^2+a^2e^4
\quad\text{(subtracting }4e^2c^2ad\text{ from both sides)}\\
\iff\\
0\lt (dc^2-ae^2)^2
\quad\text{(noticing the factorization)}\\
\end{array}
$